# JQuery focus not working via new 1.7.1 .on() method for Ajax returned html

Tags: jquery

Ok, I'm against a wall on this one, so any help much appreciated.

I have an html input field:

(with id: `#data_input` ) that was returned via an ajax call.

I then check that before the form is submitted for input on the `#data_input` field.

(note: I'm on v1.7.1 of jquery)

If nothing is entered I change the css of the field to highlight it to red via:

```
$('#data_input').css('background-color','red')
```

and that works fine so I can target it fine. But I then run into an issue when I try to undo the red background when the user enters the field via:

```
$('#data_input').on('focus', function(){$(this).css('background-color','white')});
```

but I get nothing.,   Any ideas?

`.live()` and `.focus()` also dont work :(

Comment: Are you saying the successful `.css()` call is _after_ the field is loaded via ajax? If you've put that `.on()` call in the success callback of your ajax it should work. Try a `console.log()` in the focus function instead of setting css, to confirm if the function gets called at all. And please show a bit more of your code, particularly the context of the lines you've already shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Updated to use .on on dynamic elements.

The same scenario works for me.. See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/upWBU/4/) here and the code is below,

**HTML:**

```
<div id="result" ></div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#result').on ('focus', '#input_field', function () {
    $(this).css ('background-color', 'white');
});

$('#result').on ( 'click', '#submit', function () {
    if ($('#input_field').text() == '') {
        $('#input_field').css ('background-color', 'red');
    }
});

//added to dom after the binding. see above code.
$('#result').append('<input type="text" value="" id="input_field" />' +
                    '<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />');
```

Comment: Nice demo, but that isn't quite the same scenario since your input is in the page from the start, while the OP's is loaded via ajax.

Comment: Thx! @Vega It was as you stated, use of the .on worked.  Basically any dynamically loaded DOM object via AJAX for example need to be detected byway of an .on handler on a containing parent that was not dynamically loaded... and bam! It works every time.

Answer (score 0):

1. See if the code you are writing works with a field not returned by ajax.
2. I assume you have checked to make sure the focus function is called at all.
3. Try an onchange handler.
4. Try your css through .addClass()
5. Demand your money back ;)
6. Try .focus(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('focus', '#data_input', function(){$(this).css('background-color','white')});
```